# I am putting 2 drives into a Dell poweredge 860 server. What's the best way to do backups?

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I am planning on running Ubuntu. What's the best setup to back up things? So if one fails, I can just swap files and site can keep running. Is there a mirroring program I should use? or does Ubuntu comes with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the machine itself doesn't come with a RAID controller, you can set it up right in Ubuntu.  Here's a quick walkthrough: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID

This won't do anything for actual backups but will provide protection against a single disk failure within the computer itself.  You still might want to perform regular backups of your server to another location so you can rebuild a new system with your data and configuration if the server completely fails.

Answer (score 2):

I think KenJ is right on the money HOWEVER I MUST WARN YOU ... 
**RAID IS NOT A SUBSTITUTE FOR BACKUPS**

We have been hired many times to Fix what has been broken on a RAIDED system.
In short - a Mirror will of course mirror everything - including accidentally deleted files, hacked systems etc...

Make sure to have a backup & DONT HAVE THE BACKUP on the SAME system...

Ubuntu is a great OS - and has many options for backups... 
tell us what you are using @ home... or elsewhere and we can suggest a FREE backup system to go offsite or to another system w/ your files (such as Rsync)

Comment: thanks for info. What software do you suggest? It's a clean install. So what do you think works best? Besides getting this dedicated server, I have shared hosting with hostgator with unlimited space. So I suppose I could back it up to there. Wise or dumb?

Comment: IF YOU DO MAKE SURE TO LOCK THAT DIRECTORY DOWN 

What you could do - is use an rsync script - run it from the hostgator side and make sure the folder you sync to is not in public_html